# Context Menu doesn't appear at the right position (Angular)

Tags: angular

I have a table and want to show a context menu when the user clicks on a row. However currently the context menu appears in the top left corner even though I assign the mouse position value to X and Y.

Here are some code snippets to help you see what I did:

**HTML**

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr
        mat-row
        routerLink="/ticket-details/{{ row.id }}"
        *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
        (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, row)"
      >
        <div
          style="position: absolute"
          [style.left.px]="contextMenuPosition.x"
          [style.top.px]="contextMenuPosition.y"
          [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu"
          [matMenuTriggerData]="{ row: Ticket }"
        ></div>
      </tr>
```

**Component**

```
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger)
  contextMenu: MatMenuTrigger;

  contextMenuPosition = { x: '0px', y: '0px' };

onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent, ticket: Ticket) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.clientX  + ',' + event.clientY + ',' + ticket.subject);
    this.contextMenuPosition.x = event.clientX + 'px';
    this.contextMenuPosition.y = event.clientY + 'px';
    this.contextMenu.menuData = { ticket : Ticket };
    this.contextMenu.openMenu();
  }
```

The console log shows me that the correct data with the proper values gets passed. I used [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-context-menu-table?file=app%2Fcontext-menu-example.html) as inspiration where it works correct and also has an animation which mine does not have for some reason.

I tried playing around with removing the "px" part in the component or changing [style.left.px] to [style.left] but to no avail.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself after more fiddling around. Should have thought about this before writing this questions.

The X/Y Coordinates were of type string and after I removed the "px" appendix and used [style.left.px] it worked like a charm also with animations